# Java need help improve challenging regex

Tags: java, regex

We have a business rule which look like below:

```
String S= "IF (A=3 AND B=2)=0 AND IF(c=4 AND D=5)=1 AND (AGE>=15 AND AGE<=45)"
```

I have to split the above string into three parts like below:

```
IF (A=3 AND B=2)=0   
IF(c=4 AND D=5)=1
(AGE>=15 AND AGE<=45)
```

I have tried with the following regular expression for `[^AND].*\\)=0|1`  to split, i am getting the first two but not the last one `(AGE>=15 AND AGE<=45)`.

Can anyone help me with this ? What I am missing?

Comment: Why don't you use s.split("AND")? Are you tied to using regexp for finding groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String s =
        "IF (A=3 AND B=2)=0 AND IF(c=4 AND D=5)=1 AND (AGE>=15 AND AGE<=45)";
    Pattern exprPattern = Pattern.compile("(IF\\s*\\(.*?\\)=[01]|\\(.*\\))");
    Matcher m = exprPattern.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("* " + m.group());
    }
```

This tries to identify the three parts by two alternative sub-patterns:

```
    (
        IF\\s*\\(.*?\\)=[01]
    |
        \\(.*\\)
    )
```

The `.*?` ensures that the shortest sequence is matched of the entire pattern.

Comment: Excellent Sir :) , i learned how to use sub-patterns from this solution.thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Split on `AND` when not within brackets by asserting (via look ahead) that the next bracket char (if any) is an open bracket:

```
String[] parts = str.split(" *AND *(?=[^)]*(\\(|$))");
```

Here's some test code that shows this works:

```
String str = "IF (A=3 AND B=2)=0 AND IF(c=4 AND D=5)=1 AND (AGE>=15 AND AGE<=45)";
String[] parts = S.split(" *AND *(?=[^)]*(\\(|$))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString( parts));
```

Output:

```
[IF (A=3 AND B=2)=0, IF(c=4 AND D=5)=1, (AGE>=15 AND AGE<=45)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code:

```
String s = "IF (A=3 AND B=2)=0 AND IF(c=4 AND D=5)=1 AND (AGE>=15 AND AGE<=45)";

for (String part : s.split("AND (?=[^)]*(\\(|$))")) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

Produces:

```
IF (A=3 AND B=2)=0 
IF(c=4 AND D=5)=1 
(AGE>=15 AND AGE<=45)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "IF (A=3 AND B=2)=0 AND IF(c=4 AND D=5)=1 AND (AGE>=15 AND AGE<=45)";

 String[] a =s.split("(?<=(\\)=[01]))\\sAND\\s");
             for(String d:a){
                 System.out.println(d);
             }
```

output

```
IF (A=3 AND B=2)=0
IF(c=4 AND D=5)=1
(AGE>=15 AND AGE<=45)
```